# Crystal Reports - Sum Records and display in detail section

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, summary

I'm pretty new to CR and this is stumping me.  I have two SQL tables, let's call them Invoice and AdditionalCosts.  AdditionalCosts is linked to Invoice by invoice number.  My report prints details regarding invoices for a particular day.  AdditionalCosts can have multiple records for an invoice.  I need to sum the costs and display the total with the invoice in the detail section.

I have several groups already and I tried adding an additional group for invoice number.  I then suppressed the detail section.  That works for the total of additional costs but it also sums the other fields in the report (total price, total cost, etc) if there are multiple records in AdditionalCosts.

Comment: Unless you add summary to some field it doesn't get summarized have you added summary for total price and total cost?can you post your report structure?

Comment: I'll be glad to post my report structure.  How do I do that?

Comment: Just post how your groups are and where your fields are in design and where you are trying to view summary